# VBA resize image with animation

Tags: vba, timer, vb6

The code below animates the resizing effect properly but from the left corner of the image. How can it be done from the center expanding in all directions?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

If Image1.Width >= 2916 Then
    Image1.Width = 2916
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Exit Sub
End If
Image1.Width = Image1.Width + 50
Image1.Height = Image1.Height + 50
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (untested):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

If Image1.Width >= 2916 Then
    Image1.Width = 2916
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Exit Sub
End If

Image1.Left = Image1.Left - 25
Image1.Width = Image1.Width + 50
Image1.Top = Image1.Top - 25
Image1.Height = Image1.Height + 50

End Sub
```

Comment: It expands, but not from the center

Comment: My mistake ... see revised version